# LibreOffice Calc (7.2.5.2) replaces moved cells with non-template font family and size

Tags: libreoffice, fonts, templates, style

I created a simple Calc template modifying all cells (`Ctrl+A`) to use `FreeMono 12pt`, and have Set as default template. (`File > Templates > Save as Template... > apply name > check "Set as default template" > Save`)

If I insert columns, or rows or cells; the template font family and size are applied to the new cells.

If I select a group of cells and move them to a different location on the sheet, the cells that replace those moved (in the original location) revert to the "factory" style of `Liberation Sans 10pt`.

Is there any way to adjust this "factory" style to match the template font family and size?

**Additional information**:

**OS**; Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS x86_64 fresh install at release of 20.04, fully updated daily.

**LibreOffice** upgraded to **7.2.5.2**: the issue remains.

Comment: @fedkad Added to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You followed the wrong approach. Ctrl+a then formattng all cells applies direct formatting to each cell. Not only does that increase the size of your file, it also causes the effects you see: direct formatting is not default formatting.

You instead want to [change the cell styles](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjNtMrboc_1AhXPzKQKHTCcAm0QFnoECAsQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocumentation.libreoffice.org%2Fassets%2FUploads%2FDocumentation%2Fen%2FCG4.1%2FPDF%2FCG4104-StylesAndTemplates.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3bS96oOerH6048EilwMMfp), then save the template and set it as default.

Comment: That approach seems to have worked, thank you. But the documentation bares little to no relation to the options and steps available in the application. e.g. had to right click the Default style and select Modify... But I got there in the end!